# Meaning of MATLAB logistic regression coeficients

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, matlab

Suppose that I'm using this function to implement logistic regression in `MATLAB R2015a`:

```
[coefs,~,stats] = glmfit(TrainInputs,TrainTargets,'binomial','logit'); % Logistic regression
```

I have ten continues inputs and a binary output (1 and 0). This is the `coefs` output of above function:

```
coefs = 
2.04869088486007
-4.66230054501349
0.355690380077187
-1.87230109681715
6.85763253382301
3.46437006313075
-0.282766819896174
-1.08763387246821
-1.94250600133904
1.46621342829667
-2.83661766065114
```

What is meaning of the `coefs` in logistic regression of `MATLAB`? Suppose that input names are `X1 to X10`. If we have `1 %` increase in `X1`, We have `-4.66%` increase in probability of being `class 1`?

Comment: The duplicate includes logistic regression as a special case. The first part of my answer addresses it directly.  It concludes, "Thus, $\beta_m$ is the marginal change in log odds with respect to $X_m$."

Comment: @whube . Thank you for comment. for a negative value like `-4.6623` we have `exp(-4.6623)=0.0094`. So now we have a positive value. We should consider negative sign here or positive sign? `a one-unit change in the variable corresponding to "X1" will multiply the relative risk of the outcome (negative or positive?) (compared to the base outcome) by 0.0094` ?

Comment: Maybe that's correct--but all your parentheses and mischaracterizations get in the way of being sure of what you are saying. A [relative risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk) cannot be negative. An exponentiated value cannot be negative. There is no meaning in "compared to the base outcome": a relative risk *already* involves a comparison.

Comment: Can you revise this sentence with this new negative coefficient? `a one-unit change in the variable corresponding...` .

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, user2991243; you can apply that interpretation in the linear regression model, while the interpretation of $\beta$ coefficient in the logistic regression model is pretty different, because of the logit transformation and the fact that $\beta$ coefficients are odds ratios and, so, not linear in the probability.

[Here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/odds_ratio.htm) you can find the explanation of such transformation and the relative interpretation (using stata).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So for example for `X4` with value of `6.85763253382301` : we will see 10461% !! increase in the odds of output for a one-unit increase in `x4`. `exp(6.85763253382301) = 951.1127` and `11%*951=10461` ??